# How to configure to require user to change password after create/reset in RHEL 5

Tags: linux, security, rhel5

I have to configure system RHEL5 to ensure the security. One requirement is:

> When a password is first created or
>   reset by an administrator authorized
>   to do so, system(RHEL 5) shall require
>   the owner of the account to change the
>   password the next time he logs on.

I don't know how to configure to meet this requirement.
Could anyone help me with this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
passwd USERNAME
chage -d 0 USERNAME
```

where `USERNAME` is replaced with the real username.  I find that the order of these commands is important (ie, don't set the password after the chage).